# Use tail recursion to achieve repeated function composition

Tags: scheme, racket, repeat, tail-recursion, function-composition

I need to define a function `(repeat-write n f)` so that
`((repeat-write n f) x)` evaluates to `(f (f (... (f x) ...)))`
where there are `n` applications of the function `f`.

For example:

```
((repeat-write 4 cdr) ’(1 2 3 4 5 6))
```

evaluates to

```
’(5 6)
```

I'm not too sure how to get started on this..

Comment: [this later answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64063040/849891) actually answers the Q.

Answer (score 3):

### tail-recursive solution for `repeat-compose` without using `compose`

We define a tail-recursive local helper-function `%repeat-compose` and put a `lambda` around its call to return a curryfied function.

```
(define (repeat-compose n f)
  (define (%repeat-compose n f (acc nil))
    (cond ((<= n 0) acc)
          (else (%repeat-compose (- n 1) f (f acc)))))
  (lambda (x)
    (%repeat-compose n f x)))
```

Let's try it:

```
((repeat-compose 3 cdr) '(a b c d e))
;; '(d e)
```

It works also by defining like this:

```
(define ((repeat-compose n f) x)
  (define (%repeat-compose n f (acc nil))
    (cond ((<= n 0) acc)
          (else (%repeat-compose (- n 1) f (f acc)))))
  (%repeat-compose n f x))
```

### Now, with a similar trick, you can define your own `compose` in a tail-recursive manner!

```
(define (compose . functions)
    (define (%compose functions acc)
      (cond ((empty? functions) acc)
            (else (%compose (cdr functions) ((car functions) acc)))))
    (lambda (x)
      (%compose functions x)))
;; or:
(define ((compose . functions) x)
    (define (%compose functions acc)
      (cond ((empty? functions) acc)
            (else (%compose (cdr functions) ((car functions) acc)))))
    (%compose functions x))

((compose cdr cdr cdr car) '(a b c d e f))
;; 'd ;; works!
```

### non-recursive solution using `compose`

Use `apply` and `compose`.

```
(define (repeat-compose n f)
  (apply compose (make-list n f)))
```

`apply` requires a function and a list of arguments.
`(make-list n el)` creates a list by repeating n-times an element.

`(repeat-compose 5 f)` executes `(apply compose (list f f f f f))` which is equivalent to `(compose f f f f f)` returning a function executing 5-times `f` on a given argument.

```
((repeat-compose 5 cdr) '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
;; '(6 7)
```

### similar solution using `compose` and explicite `lambda`

```
(define (repeat-compose n f)
  (lambda (x) ((apply compose (make-list n f)) x)))

((repeat-compose 3 cdr) '(1 2 3 4 5))
;; '(4 5)
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to use `list` for `(list f f f f f)` and not `'` quote which turns every `f` into a symbol instead of a function

Comment: What a wild, energetic answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

To get started on this, we could try defining

```
(define ((repeat-compose 4 f) x)
   (f (f (f (f x)))))
```

and also

```
(define ((repeat-compose 3 f) x)
   (f (f (f x))))
```

and

```
(define ((repeat-compose 2 f) x)
   (f (f x)))
```

and

```
(define ((repeat-compose 1 f) x)
   (f x))
```

and

```
(define ((repeat-compose 0 f) x)
   x)
```

This is not a valid Racket though. For starters we can't have several definitions at once, in Racket, even if mutually exclusive. We need to write it as a `cond`,

```
(define ((repeat-compose n f) x)
   (cond
      ((= n 4) (f (f (f (f x)))) )
      ((= n 3) (f (f (f x))) )
      ((= n 2) (f (f x)) )
      ((= n 1) (f x) )
      ((<= n 0) x )))       ;; let's use `<=` here
```

This is valid Racket now but of course still unsatisfactory. What if `n` is greater than `4`?

But wait, do you see a pattern there? Of course it does exactly like we wanted, for `n=4` it calls the function `f` 4 times, for `n=3` it calls it 3 times, i.e. one less time than for `n=4`. So let's write this down:

```
(define ((repeat-compose n f) x)
   (cond
      ((= n 4) (f ((repeat-compose (- n 1) f) x)) )
               ;; ------------------------------;
      ((= n 3) (f (f (f x))) )
      ((= n 2) (f (f x)) )
      ((= n 1) (f x) )
      ((<= n 0) x )))
```

But that's also the same as

```
(define ((repeat-compose n f) x)
   (cond
      ((= n 4) (f ((repeat-compose (- n 1) f) x)) )
      ((= n 3) (f ((repeat-compose (- n 1) f) x)) )
      ((= n 2) (f ((repeat-compose (- n 1) f) x)) )
      ((= n 1) (f ((repeat-compose (- n 1) f) x)) )
      ((<= n 0) x )))
```

isn't it? And what's so special about `4` anyway, why should we be artificially demanding `n` to be any specific number, isn't any `n` that is greater than `0` handled in exactly the same way?

So now we can simplify it just a little bit more, taking care that *all* cases are handled, and that's that.

It's not *tail*-recursive, yes, but it is recursive, and it is *correct*, which is the most important thing. So it gets you started. Just follow the same pattern of thought, and write down the corresponding transformation in the tail-recursive fashion. In particular,

```
(define ((repeat-compose n f) x)
   (cond
      ((> n 0) (   (repeat-compose (- n 1) f) (____ x) ))
                ;; --------------------------  ^^^^ fill the blanks
```

might do the trick. Or maybe you will have to define a helper inner function with unnested applications to make it more self-evidently *tail*-recursive.

Comment: Gotcha.. This definitely satisfies the example but I'm wondering how tail recursion can be used in this..

Comment: well it's not tail-recursive, but it is recursive, and it is correct, which is the most important thing. so it gets you started.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help! I will try and build on this..

Comment: I'm getting the below error when i try to run the final code, how do i get past this?

```
define: expected the name of the function, but found a part
```

Comment: for a new question with the new code, please post the new question in a new separate post, including all relevant info and code, possibly with link to this post for background reference.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`for/fold`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#(form._((lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt)._for%2Ffold))) is also an option:

```
(define ((repeat-compose n f) x)
  (for/fold ([acc x]) ([i (in-range n)]) (f acc)))
```

Using it:

```
> ((repeat-compose 4 cdr) (list 1 2 3 4 5 6))
(list 5 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`power`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/relation/Composing_Operations.html#%28def._%28%28lib._relation%2Fcomposition..rkt%29._power%29%29) function is meant for exactly this kind of thing:

```
(require relation)
((power cdr 4) '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
```

`=> '(5 6)`

`power` works for any type and composition operation, not only function composition.

*[disclosure: I'm the author of this utility]*

Comment: does it make use of exponentiation by repeated squaring, to create more compact representations of the constructed functions when `n` is large?

Comment: @WillNess Did not know about this optimization but it's brilliant. It doesn't currently do it this way but I'd definitely be interested in adding this.

Comment: yeah, just had that thought pop into my head back when I was reading your answer. :)

Comment: actually, it was in the context of writing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64072035/849891).

Comment: Thanks for sharing :)