# Solving a functional programming problem using dr.racket

Tags: function, functional-programming, scheme, racket

I am trying to implement a function called `funPower`, which takes a function `f`, an integer `n` and returns the function `f^n`. For example `((funPower sqrt 2) 16)` should return *2*, which is `(sqrt (sqrt 16))`.

This is what I have so far but it is not giving me correct output

```
(define (funPower f n)
  (lambda(x) (if (<= n 1)
            (f x)
            (f (funPower f (- n 1)) x))))
```

Comment: What have you tried/done? This looks like a homework problem, and we can't do homework for you.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how `((funPower sqrt 2) 16)` is supposed to return `2`? What were the operations you did there?

Comment: @ÓscarLópez  He wants a function that waits for an input and applies N times a function F on that input. For example, `\x->sqrt(sqrt(x))`.  It's a problem from SICP as far as remember.

Answer (score 2):

First, you're missing one more pair of parens.

```
(define (funPower1 f n)
  (lambda (x) (if (<= n 1)
            (f x)
         ;; (f (   funPower1 f (- n 1)) x))))
            (f ( ( funPower1 f (- n 1)) x)))) )
         ;;     ^^^                          ^^^
```

because `(funPower1 f (- n 1))` returns a *function* to be called on **`x`**, the future argument value, as you show with the example, `((funPower sqrt 2) 16)`.

Second, it's `<= 0`, not `<= 1`, and the function `f` shouldn't be called at all in such a case:

```
(define (funPower2 f n)
  (lambda (x) (if (<= n 0)
         ;; (f x)      ^^^
               x 
            (f ( ( funPower2 f (- n 1)) x)))) )
```

Now that it's working, we see that it defers the decisions to the final call time, of `((funPower f n) x)`. But it really could do all the decisions upfront -- the `n` is already known.

To achieve that, we need to swap the `(lambda` and the `(funPower`, to push the lambda *"in"*. When we do, it'll become an additional argument to such augmented `funPower`:

```
(define (funPower3 f n)
  (if (<= n 0) (lambda (x) 
               x )
    (funPower3 f (- n 1) (lambda (x) (f x)))) )
```

Now *this* is completely out of sync. Where's that third argument?

```
(define (funPower4 f n fun)
  (if (<= n 0) fun
    (funPower4 f (- n 1) (lambda (x) (fun (f x)))) ))
```

That's a little bit better, but what's the `fun`, originally? Where does it come from? It must always  be `(lambda (x) x)` at first or else it won't be right. The solution is to make it an internal definition and use that, supplying it the correct argument the first time we call it:

```
(define (funPower5 f n)
  (define (loop n fun)
    (if (<= n 0) fun
      (loop (- n 1) 
            (lambda (x) (fun (f x))))))
  (loop n (lambda (x) x)))
```

This kind of thing would normally be coded as a named `let`,

```
(define (funPower5 f n)
  (let loop ((n  n) 
             (fun (lambda (x) x)))
    (if (<= n 0) fun
      (loop (- n 1) 
            (lambda (x) (fun (f x)))))))
```

We could also try creating simpler functions in the simpler cases. For instance, we could return `f` itself if `n` is `1`:

```
(define (funPower6 f n)
  (cond 
    ((zero? n) .....)
    ((= n 1)   .....)
    ((< n 0)   .....)
    (else
      (let loop ((n  n) 
                 (fun .....))
        (if (= n .....) fun
          (loop (- n 1) 
            (lambda (x) (fun (f x)))))))))
```

Complete it by filling in the blanks.

More substantive further improvement is to use exponentiation by repeated squaring -- both in constructing the resulting function, and to have it used by the function we construct!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
(define funpow
  (lambda (f n)
    ((lambda (s) (s s n (lambda (x) x)))
     (lambda (s n o)
       (if (zero? n)
           o
           (s s (- n 1)
              (lambda (x)
                (o (f x)))))))))

    
(define sqrt_2 (funpow sqrt 2))
(define pow2_2 (funpow (lambda (x) (* x x)) 2))

(sqrt_2 16)
(pow2_2 2)
```